# How to use python regex sub

Tags: python, regex, string, python-3.x, pattern-matching

I'm trying to substitute the following string

```
word = 'hello contractor salary hour year'
```

with the pattern

```
pattern = r'\b(contrator|per|salary|year|hour)'
word = re.sub(pattern, '', word, re.I)
```

but not all words are replaced 
I get the result 'hello  hour year'
Do you know how I can fix it?

Thanks for the answer from Kirill Bulygin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a common gotcha, use `flags=` (`re.sub(pattern, '', word, flags=re.I)`). Otherwise the artificial number designated by `re.I` is used as `count`.

Comment: Thanks, it works, but would you mind explaining the reason of it?

Comment: yes, it's good, but if I add some other rules like (...| month(ly)?|...), it fails again, do you know why?

Comment: All I can tell from the information you gave is that it's unrelated to `re.I` or `count`. I would recommend to create a new question and include your code, the input, the actual output and the desired output.

Comment: thanks...I forget to pass the flags =... sorry about that.